# Comparing a string to a part of string inside an arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, comparison

The title may be a little confusing or misleading but I'm trying to compare a single string:

```
String mystring = "abc";
```

And then try to compare it with every single string contained in an arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("The first letters of the alphabet are abc");
array.add("abc");
array.add("Alphabet");
array.add("Nothing");
```

But (and I'm not certain) it seems that contains is true only if both strings matches and not if the word or phrase is inside the string.

How can I compare a desired string to a "phrase" that is within an `ArrayList` of strings?

Comment: As long as it's case sensitive, you could loop through the array and use `.contains(mystring);`

Comment: @AntonH consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I didn't want to because he doesn't specify if it needs to be case insensitive, in which case my answer would be incorrect.

Comment: @AntonH you could add another section in your answer about how to solve this probably by using a third party library like [`StringUtils#containsIgnoreCase`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) from Apache Commons Lang.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I keep forgetting about the Apache Commons. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Please **post your real problem** instead of just giving portions of it. In that way, you could receive more accurate help instead of attempts of a possible-non-solution.

Comment: Im sorry about that but i just noticed the real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check what you're asking for, you would have to iterate through the values that are contained in the array, and check whether they **contain** the value of the string that you want to check.

```
for (String fromArray : array) {
    if (fromArray.contains(mystring)) {
        // put your code here
    }
}
```

This method is **case sensitive**. To overcome this, you can either change the strings to lowercase (with the `toLowerCase()` method), or use a library that has been designed to do so. One such library is the Apache Commons library.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

If you want to check whether the array element, instead of containing, instead *matches* the string you want to check it against, you would use the `matches()` method.

Documentation links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

[Apache commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
// check if string is exist in array
if(array.Contains("YourString"))
{
// if contain then u can use this or do operations
Response.Write("YourString is available in array");
}
```

this will help you

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

You use an Iterator over the ArrayList.

```
for(String s: array):
  if(s.toLowerCase().contains(myString.toLowerCase())) { //find if such a substring exits within each string
      //do something
    }
}
```

If however you don't want to check case sensitive-ness you get remove the toLowerCase() from the lines.

I hope you are aware of what toLowerCase() does and putting it in the code doesn't makes a difference for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need iterate through all the elements of Array List and then need to check using `contains()` method

```
for (String str : array){
            if(str.contains(mystring)){
                System.out.println(str + " Conatins" + mystring);
            }
        }
```